# How to setup xa datasource using Spring and weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, weblogic

I am having an issue creating xa datasources in spring 4.0.

I have setup my datasources in weblogic using an xa driver.
I then added added jndi-lookups for the data sources in spring:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceOne" jndi-name="/jdbc/XAONE" resource-ref="true" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceTwo" jndi-name="/jdbc/XATWO" resource-ref="true" />
```

I have then created the configuration for the entity managers:

```
<bean id="emfone" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceOne" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="..." />
</bean>

<bean id="emftwo"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTwo" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="..." />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
</bean>
```

After this I have my transaction manager configured:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emfone" />
    <qualifier value="tmOne"/>
</bean>

<bean id="docTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emftwo" />
    <qualifier value="tmTwo"/>
</bean>
```

I have a service class method annotated with @Transactional that calls a DAO. The DAO uses both entity managers for persisting data.

When the DAO tries to persist using the emftwo a no transaction in progress error is thrown. Does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a single JTA transaction manager instead? You are currently overriding the JTA one with a local one. You should remove both the `JpaTransactionManager`s and setup hibernate to use JTA transactions by setting the correct jtaplatform (I would say the `WeblogicJtaPlatform` to integrate with Weblogic and have proper tx propagation.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried using the WebLogicJtaTransactionManager in place of the jta-transaction-manager and jpaTransactionManagers though I get a "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query" error in that case for any updates in either datasource

Comment: Read my comment again. I nowhere mentioned the `WebLogicJtaTransactionManager` I mentioned the `WeblogicJtaPlatform` for configuring hibernate properly. The `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` should already add the `WebLogicJtaTransactionManager` however you are currently overwriting it with a `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, How do you set the WeblogicJtaPlatform? I have tried setting the jpa properties (and within jpa properties the hibernate.transaction.jta.platform) within the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. Though this did not work

Comment: Also the error is a little different. Now the following is thrown when I try to update using either datasource:  javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query